# Android Preferences update

Tags: android, preferences

I have created a PreferenceScreen with a few checkboxes.

One of them is:

```
 <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="Show facebook popup"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:summary="Share Your score on facebook"
            android:key="showFbCheck"/>
```

I want to update this CheckBox from another activity, How this can be achieved?

10X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as the two activities are in the same application, you simply tell the other activity load the sharedPreferences with the same KEY that your preference activity uses.  There's a whole page on preferences in the SDK:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref